# Incorrect multi-variate anomaly detection - Isolation Forest Python

Tags: anomaly-detection, python-3.x, ensemble-learning, isolation-forest

My data looks like below. it has 333 rows and 2 columns. Clearly the first row is anomaly.

ndf:

```
   +----+---------+-------------+
|    | ROW_CNT |    TOT_SALE |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  0 |      45 |     1411.27 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |   47754 |  1596200.68 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  2 |  105894 |  3750304.55 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  3 |  372953 | 14368324.86 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  4 |  389915 | 14899302.85 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  5 |  379473 | 14696309.67 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  6 |  388571 | 14679457.93 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  7 |  234409 |  8226472.95 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  8 |   50587 |  1673114.75 |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  9 |  383779 | 14614106.80 |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 10 |  391525 | 14907049.92 |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 11 |  392012 | 13482471.85 |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 12 |  379081 | 14324222.03 |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 13 |  383681 | 14478162.98 |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 14 |  228857 |  7994892.44 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

I am using below function to detect anomaly on 2 columns in the dataset:

```
def outlier_func(df):
    model = IsolationForest(behaviour='new',n_estimators=1000,  max_samples='auto', 
    contamination='auto', max_features=1.0)  
    model.fit(df[['ROW_CNT', 'TOT_SALE']])
    df['scores'] = model.decision_function(df[['ROW_CNT', 'TOT_SALE']])
    df['anomaly'] = model.predict(df[['ROW_CNT', 'TOT_SALE']])
    anomaly = df.loc[df['anomaly'] == -1]
    anomaly_index = list(anomaly.index)
    return anomaly          

outlier_func(ndf)
```

What am i missing that it is incorrectly detecting the anomaly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you know beforehand the percentage of outliers present in your data, you should set the parameter `contamination` this will be the threshold used for the `predict` method to label the data as outlier/inlier. In your case it is `~ .06`

**Code:**

```
isoForest = IsolationForest(random_state= 42, contamination= .06).fit(frame)
frame["outlier"] = isoForest.score_samples(frame[["row_cnt", "tot_sale"]])
frame["class"] = isoForest.predict(frame[["row_cnt", "tot_sale"]])
```

**Outputs:**

```
   row_cnt  tot_sale    outlier  class
0   45      1411.27     -0.682933  -1
1   47754   1596200.68  -0.532250   1
2   105894  3750304.55  -0.623476   1
3   372953  14368324.86 -0.486222   1
4   389915  14899302.85 -0.432155   1
5   379473  14696309.67 -0.426700   1
6   388571  14679457.93 -0.412645   1
7   234409  8226472.95  -0.575458   1
8   50587   1673114.75  -0.530636   1
9   383779  14614106.80 -0.408078   1
10  391525  14907049.92 -0.440645   1
11  392012  13482471.85 -0.561618   1
12  379081  14324222.03 -0.439916   1
13  383681  14478162.98 -0.417980   1
14  228857  7994892.44  -0.577208   1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve the efficiency of the prediction is to convert the dataframe type to float32. I got better result while converting the data type to float32.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[45,1411.27],[47754,1596200.68],[105894,3750304.55],[372953,14368324.86],[389915,14899302.85]]),columns=['ROW_CNT','TOT_SALE'],dtype=np.float32)
def outlier_func(df):
    model = IsolationForest(behaviour='new',n_estimators=1000,  max_samples='auto', 
    contamination='auto', max_features=1.0)  
    model.fit(df[['ROW_CNT', 'TOT_SALE']])
    df['scores'] = model.decision_function(df[['ROW_CNT', 'TOT_SALE']])
    df['anomaly'] = model.predict(df[['ROW_CNT', 'TOT_SALE']])
    anomaly = df.loc[df['anomaly'] == -1]
    anomaly_index = list(anomaly.index)
    return anomaly          

outlier_func(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, in my dataset, only first row is the anomaly only first row should have -1. I tried converting the dataframe to float but it does not help. Thank for trying though.

Comment: could you please share your dataset, want to know how the data varies

Comment: Added first 15 rows.. I hope it helps